# How to move save menu from one NSWindow to another?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

In my OSX app I have a launch window that looks like following:

[image]

Next to the name of the window there is a little triangle, which is the save menu option. I don't want it there, instead I want it on a different window that appears after the new project is opened.

Does anyone know how to do that?

I'm making my windows programmatically, not in the nib by the way, and my app is document based.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I mean, didn't you add the little triangle there in the first place? Why don't you just remove it and place it wherever you want?

Comment: well...to be honest I have no idea where did it come from

Comment: didn't you create the windows programmatically? a little triangle doesn't just appear by default...

Comment: I did create that window programmatically, but have no idea why the triangle is there...that's why I'm asking this question :)))

Comment: Well can you show us some code?

Comment: I know this triangle only when using a document based app. The triangle comes from `NSDocument` and preservingVersions set to `YES`. You will get it in every window of your app that is connected to the `NSDocument`window controller. To achieve this, you will need to add new windows to the documents window controller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you tell me where preservingVersions can be set? I can't find it in the reference documentation.